# How do you fix the auto-scrolling kik does for text input on iOS 7.1 devices?

Tags: kik

Our text input field is centered in the screen and set up not to move. Behavior is proper on all platform variants except for Kik on iOS 7.1 and 8.
[Here it is on the native 7.1 browser working properly](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz3Ul33L3EdRakpMdUJ6Yk5DN2c/edit?usp=sharing).
[Here it is inside kik with the content shifted up](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz3Ul33L3EdRYWZ5TUotU1NScVk/edit?usp=sharing).

We've tried a couple workarounds like controlling scroll/animation/propagation, but nothing has worked.

What's the proper way to keep content from shifting on input inside Kik on the new iOS?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually the result of using the meta viewport tag on mobile. If you have specified the viewport sizing to be exactly the device height/width then the iOS webview will move the webview around to accommodate the keyboard rather than resizing it.

Try removing device-width/height from the viewport declaration.